# How can I create the same multiple folders in many Folders?

Tags: python, directory

I have several folders. For each of these folders, I want to create 4 folders (the same 4 folders in all the other folders).

Here is the Python code I used, but it doesn't work:

```py
import os

listOfIds = [101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,201,202,203,204,205,207,209,212,213,214,219,220,221,222,223,225,227,228,231,232,233,234,236,237,239,240,241,242,245,247,249,252,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,401,402,403,404,406,408,409,410,412,413,414,416,418,419,420,421,422,423,427,428,429,431,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,501,503,505,506,508,509,510,511,512,514,516,517,520,522,524,526,527,529,601,602,603,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,613,614,616,617,618,621,623,624,627,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,637,638,640,642,644,645,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,657,658,661,701,806,807,808,811,812,813,817,818,821,822,823,824,825,826,827,828,2003,2008,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2017,2019]
folders = ['Financial Statement','Corporate Profit','News']

root_path = 'F:/alkhaleej_pdf/BoursaKuwait_Pdfs/'+str(id)

for id in listOfIds:
    for folder in folders:
        path = os.path.join(root_path, folder) 
        os.mkdir(folder)
```

`listOfIds` is an array which contains the names of all the folders; `folders`, instead, contains the name of the folders that I need to create in all the elements of `listOfIds`.

When I run this code, I get the following error :

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Unable to create an already existing file: 'Financial Statement'
```

While the `listOfIds` folders are empty.

Comment: You never use `id`. It's a bad idea to re-use a built in as a variable name anyways

Comment: financial statemtn shownin error because it already exist in your drive in same location. first remove this folder or give remove function to remove using if else condition

Comment: No i don't have any folder with the name 'Financial Statement'

Comment: I think you meant to do `os.mkdir(path)`, not `os.mkdir(folder)`.

Comment: Thank you so much John he is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line that generates `root_path` using `id` into the loop that cycles through the `listOfIds`. Also add `mkdir` for that path:

```
import os

listOfIds = [101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,201,202,203,204,205,207,209,212,213,214,219,220,221,222,223,225,227,228,231,232,233,234,236,237,239,240,241,242,245,247,249,252,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,401,402,403,404,406,408,409,410,412,413,414,416,418,419,420,421,422,423,427,428,429,431,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,501,503,505,506,508,509,510,511,512,514,516,517,520,522,524,526,527,529,601,602,603,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,613,614,616,617,618,621,623,624,627,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,637,638,640,642,644,645,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,657,658,661,701,806,807,808,811,812,813,817,818,821,822,823,824,825,826,827,828,2003,2008,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2017,2019]
folders = ['Financial Statement','Corporate Profit','News']


for id in listOfIds:
    root_path = 'F:/alkhaleej_pdf/BoursaKuwait_Pdfs/' + str(id)
    os.mkdir(root_path)
    for folder in folders:
        path = os.path.join(root_path, folder) 
        os.mkdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listOfIds = [101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,201,202,203,204,205,207,209,212,213,214,219,220,221,222,223,225,227,228,231,232,233,234,236,237,239,240,241,242,245,247,249,252,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,401,402,403,404,406,408,409,410,412,413,414,416,418,419,420,421,422,423,427,428,429,431,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,501,503,505,506,508,509,510,511,512,514,516,517,520,522,524,526,527,529,601,602,603,605,606,607,608,609,610,611,613,614,616,617,618,621,623,624,627,629,630,631,632,633,634,635,637,638,640,642,644,645,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,657,658,661,701,806,807,808,811,812,813,817,818,821,822,823,824,825,826,827,828,2003,2008,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2017,2019]
folders = ['Financial Statement','Corporate Profit','News']

global i
for i in folders:

    os.mkdir("F:\\alkhaleej_pdf\\BoursaKuwait_Pdfs\\" + f"\\{i}")

for j in list(listOfIds):

    os.mkdir("C:\\Users\\TechRahi\\Desktop\\MYPATH" + f"\\{i}" + f"\\{j}")
```